# How to click button in IE using vba

Tags: html, vba

I'm trying to click a button to download file automatically from IE using vba. but when I run vba code my other functionality work except download file. I can manually click and download file but when I try this with vba nothing get happens.

My html code for button is-

```
<button class='submit-button'  ng-click="Update()" value="Update" id = "update" > Multistate </button>
```

And my latest vba code is-

```
 Set htmlColl2 = html.getElementsByTagName("button")
 Do While html.readyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
   For Each htmlInputt In htmlColl2
     'MsgBox htmlInput.getAttribute("value")
     If InStr(1, htmlInput.innerHTML, "Multistate") Then
       'If htmlInput.getAttribute("value") = "Update" Then
       htmlInputt.Click
       Exit For
     End If
   Next htmlInputt
```

Comment: I think the issue is that there is no `onclick` event in the button but `ng-click` instead.  To test, try running this from browser developer  console. `$(".submit-button").click();`

Comment: @PortlandRunner I tried second one .It is giving runtime error 438.

Comment: @PortlandRunner and for first comment I am unaware of how to test it

Comment: press F12 on the webpage and in the window that opens up go to the console tab and enter the code from @PortlandRunner there. Then hit enter. You may need to modify if page not running jquery. No jquery use: document.querySelector("submit-button").click();    though there is an id on the node you can use instead.

Comment: @PortlandRunner  I tried it on console $(".submit-button").click() , it is giving me all data in console